# Copying an sqlite database from file to :memory using C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, memory, copy

I have a small database with tables containing a small amount of data which I need to copy into memory.

Currently I am using:

```
insertcommand.CommandText = "SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE sql NOT NULL;";
```

To pull all the table schema from the file database, however I'm not really sure how to proceed with creating these tables in the new memory database, and copying all the relevant data across.

---

In short, how do I copy an SQLite database from file to memory using C# and System.Data.SQLite?

Comment: had you able to fulfill your need?? I am also looking for the same apis in C# program. if yes please help me on this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Example 1: Loading and Saving In-Memory Databases on [the SQLite Online Backup API page.](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html)

Comment: That is fairly helpful, however, I am not sure how to use those functions when using the ADO style of System.Data.SQLite

Comment: Further research suggests that these functions are not yet available in System.Data.SQLite, but the developer states that they are "coming soon"